# Create a array with multiples index in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, multi-index

I need some help here.
I'm trying to rewrite some codes in javascript, and I'm stuck at creating a array with a multiples indexes. Typing arbitrarily, is something like this:

Those constants are the limit of each array's index

```
const index1 = 2
const index2 = 20
const index3 = 18
```

The var 'storage' is the array that I want to create.

```
storage = Array[0.."index1", 0.."index2", 0.."index3"] of Bool
```

Using random bool values, the array "storage" will result in :

```
storage[0,0,0] => true 
storage[0,0,1] => false 
storage[0,0,2] => false 
storage[0,0,3] => false 
...
storage[2,20,16] => true 
storage[2,20,17] => false 
storage[2,20,18] => true
```

end of array

How create this using JavaScript?

Comment: A multidimensional array? Or do you just want a compound key for the values?

Comment: Are you looking for `storage[0][0][0]`? Is your original code NumPy by chance?

Comment: A multidimensional array fits better. Sorry for the misexplanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do following using Multi-dimentional array:

```js
const index1 = 2;
const index2 = 20;
const index3 = 18;
let storage = new Array(index1);
for (let i = 0; i < index1; i++) {
  storage[i] = new Array(index2);
  for (let j = 0; j < index2; j++) {
    storage[i][j] = new Array(index3);
    for (let k = 0; k < index3; k++) {
      // random bool value generation
      storage[i][j][k] = (i + j + k) % 2 ? true : false;
    }
  }
}
// print the array
for (let i = 0; i < index1; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < index2; j++) {
    for (let k = 0; k < index3; k++) {
      console.log(
        "storage[" +
        i +
        "," +
        j +
        "," +
        k +
        "] => " +
        storage[i][j][k]
      );
    }
  }
}
```